# Como faço para concatenar um valor decimal?

Tags: php

Bom eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
    $numero = "5";
    $decimal = "30";   
?>
```

O que pretendo fazer é concatenar o numero, de forma a que o resultado final fique 5.3 e de forma a que os zeros a direita não contem...

Como poderei fazer isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é transformar `$numero` e `$decimal` em um valor aceito pela função [`floatval()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floatval.php).

Pra isso basta concatenar `$numero`, um ponto e `$decimal`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
$numero = "5";
$decimal = "30";
echo floatval("$numero.$decimal");  // floatval("5.30")
```

---

Lembrando que minha solução espera que `$numero` e `$decimal` contenha apenas caracteres numéricos.

Answer (score 5):

O que você deseja não é concatenar, é o oposto, é transformar textos em números, com um critério específico e fazer a soma desses números. O mais comum é usar um *cast* para fazer esta conversão, mas nada garante que ela funcionará e você pode ter problemas.

Note que criar a parte decimal do número é problema seu, só o seu código pode indicar que é isto que deseja, por isso eu dividi por 100.0 (não pode só dividir por 100 porque aí fica um valor inteiro). EU preferi converter para `int` porque há indícios que o número a ser usado não pode já ser decimal. Se você mandar fazer a concatenação antes e depois converter adicional mais um nível de possibilidade de erro.

Inacreditavelmente PHP não tem uma função pronta que gere erro se a conversão falhar (salvo eu estar bem defasado em PHP), então para ter certeza que funcionará você terá que fazer um *parser* na mão. Sem fazer isto você não pode confiar no valor, porque ele gerará o valor 0 sem indicar nada que deu erro. Eu imagino que você não pode confiar no número, então tem que validá-lo. Se pode confiar não sei se precisa fazer isto que está querendo. Coloquei no exemplo acima como o erro pode passar batido.

Não tenho certeza se é confiável, mas a função [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) pode ser a solução.

```
$numero = "5";
$decimal = "30";
echo (int)$numero + ((int)$decimal / 100.0);
echo "\n";
if (is_numeric($numero) && is_numeric($decimal)) echo (int)$numero + ((int)$decimal / 100.0);
else echo "melhor não calcular, tem erro aí";
$decimal = "a30";
echo "\n";
echo (int)$numero + ((int)$decimal / 100.0);
echo "\n";
if (is_numeric($numero) && is_numeric($decimal)) (int)$numero + ((int)$decimal / 100.0);
else echo "melhor não calcular, tem erro aí";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DqdScF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sboelhcb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/ConvertToNumber.php).

Os parênteses na segunda expressão são mais para deixar claro, eles não são necessários. Se preferir pode usar a função [`intval()`](https://ideone.com/DqdScF).

Não entrei no mérito que isto pode ser um valor monetário e isto pode ser um outro problema. Mais por curiosidade se não for isso leia [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101)

Comment: Essa parte de "falhar silenciosamente" do PHP me irrita, acho isso uma falha de design.
O python levanta uma exceção `TypeError` pra qualquer conversão sem sucesso.

Comment: Só pra constar, `is_numeric` não é tão confiável assim. Ela aceita `"+0123.45e6"` como válido, pois é uma string que representa um float mas não para este caso específico. Acho que nesse caso seria melhor checar `$numero` e `$decimal` com [`ctype_digit`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) ou uma regex mesmo.